# PHP: Download a file (CSV, PDF, ...) without using "exit" or "die"

Tags: php, download, http-headers

I got a really bad problem: I would like to create an export of CSV data. The problem is: This export is done by a controller in a MVC-application. The controller **must** reload the page after it processed all the tasks he should do.

Okay, the CSV is generated and downloaded like this:

```
/**
 * exportArrayToCSV function.
 * 
 * @access public
 * @static
 * @param mixed $array
 * @return void
 */
public static function exportArrayToCSV($array, $filename, $delimiter=";")
{
    $config                         =   JFactory::getConfig();
    $tmppath                        =   $config->get('tmp_path');

    $keys                           =   array_keys($array);

    if(is_dir($tmppath))
    {
        $filename                   =   "$filename.csv";            
        $filepath                   =   "$tmppath/$filename";
        $file                       =   new SplFileObject($filepath, 'w');

        $file->fputcsv(array_keys($array[$keys[0]]),$delimiter);

        foreach ($array as $fields) 
        {
            $file->fputcsv($fields,$delimiter);
        }

        if(file_exists($filepath))
        {   
            header ( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
            header ( 'Content-Type: application/force-download' );
            header ( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' );
            header ( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename ); 
            header ( 'Expires: 0' );
            header ( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate' );
            header ( 'Pragma: public' );
            header ( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize ($filepath) );
            ob_clean(); 
            flush();
                readfile ($filepath);
                unlink($filepath); 
            exit;
        }
        else                            return false;   
    }
    else                                return false;       
}
```

Now you see my problem: The `exit;` statement ends the controller-run and prevents the page from being reloaded. If I do not use the `exit` statement the file is not being downloaded.

So my question is: How could I download a file **without** an `exit`/`die`-Statement?

Comment: You can't send either page and file in the same stream. Otherwise the output is “mixed” and the result is a corrupted file. You **have to use `exit`** if there are other output in the following code.

Comment: Also note that even before `header` no output is allowed

Comment: Okay - so I can not use the same stream. How can I open a new stream?

Comment: What is your problem? How the user set the download request? through a form? through a link?

Comment: The problem is that the download is triggered by a toolbar-button in a `Joomla` backend (JToolbar). The button is labeled with "export" and exports a CSV set of data which is selected in a list.

Now the problem: The page does not reload after downloading and that causes that the job, which was triggered by clicking the button, is not reset from "export" to "NULL". Now if I change something in the backend view (changing the filter, searching for a keyword) the download starts again because the form has not been reloaded.

Comment: You have to use javascript for that. Through js you can change the text button

Comment: Hello fusion3k. What should I change on the text-button? The task is stored on a hidden-text-field in the template. But I guess I can not use JS in a controller...?

Comment: I don't know how your code works, but you have to change it in javascript. You can't do this with php.